# UITextField multiple lines

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield

Just wonder if it is possible to use multiple lines in UITextField in XCode. I know how to increase the height size. but have know idea about its lines :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I did it with some trick ;) First made a UITextField and increased it's size like this:

```
var frameRect: CGRect = textField.frame
frameRect.size.height = 53
textField.frame = frameRect
```

Then I made a UITextView exactly in the same area that I made my UITextField, and deleted its background colour. Now it looks like that I have a multiple lines TextField!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, UITextField is specifically one-line only.
You will need to use a UITextView instead of UITextField for displaying and editing multiline text; it will be multiline by default.

Comment: but the problem is that i have problem with how UITextView looks like ! thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can add UIImageView with needed image behind your UITextView. And set clearColor for text view.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) instead, which is a "mini-notepad" view.