# Multiline Strings in Swift

Tags: string, swift, multiline

How can I create a multiline string in Swift?
This is what I tried:

```
var myMultilineString = "This is a " + "\n" + "multiline string"
print(myMultilineString)
```

I wanted it to print:

> This is a
>
> multiline string

Comment: looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091233/swift-split-string-over-multiple-lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more than a line return between the strings but rather a real blank line, then you need two line feed characers.

```
var myMultilineString = "This is a " + "\n\n" + "multiline string"
print(myMultilineString)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Swift4 has this feature built in:

```
var myMultilineString =
"""
This is a

multiline string
"""
```

very convenient